# Android custom component works fine at runtime, but doesn't work at design time

Tags: android, xml, layout, custom-component

I am doing my first steps in Android development.
 In the meantime I am trying to create a custom component (for testing purposes) that will later be used on an Activity.

Here's the code for ClearableEditText.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ClearableEditText extends LinearLayout {

    private EditText textField;
    private Button button;

    public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.clearable_text,  this);

        setupViewItems();
    }

    private void setupViewItems() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


        this.textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        this.button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        this.textField.setText("Hello World 123");
    }    
}
```

And here's its layout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the XML layout code for the activity that will integrate the component:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SegundaActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/ativity2_text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <com.example.aplicacaoteste.ClearableEditText
        android:id="@+id/newComponent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:ems="10" >
    </com.example.aplicacaoteste.ClearableEditText>


</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run the app, the component works fine. Nonetheless, as soon as I switch to the Graphical Layout of my Activity, I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.aplicacaoteste.ClearableEditText.setupViewItems(ClearableEditText.java:36)
    at com.example.aplicacaoteste.ClearableEditText.onFinishInflate(ClearableEditText.java:26)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:754)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
```

I have no clue about what's going on in here. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: what do you mean by " as soon as I switch to the Graphical Layout of my Activity" . there is no problem with the code.

Comment: When you edit a layout in Eclipse, you can either edit it with a drag&drop user interface, or edit the corresponding XML.

The drag&drop GUI is what I meant by Graphical Layout (one of the two available tabs when you edit a layout).

Comment: you are getting the null pointer because you are not inflating it properly create the object of inflator inside the constructor and use this object to call the view like (TextView) inflator.findViewById();

Comment: There may be a bug in the tools implementation of LayoutInflater. Is line 36 the one with "this.textField.setText"?

Answer (score 0):

This source code has working perfectly. This my source code

```
package com.testapplication.customtools;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ClearableEditText  extends LinearLayout{

    private EditText textField;
    private Button button;

    public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.clearable_text,  this);

        setupViewItems();
    }

    private void setupViewItems() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


        this.textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        this.button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        this.textField.setText("Hello World 123");
    }    
}
```

This is my Main activity xml Files

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SegundaActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="test" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <com.testapplication.customtools.ClearableEditText
        android:id="@+id/newComponent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:ems="10" >
    </com.testapplication.customtools.ClearableEditText>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I am not getting any exception. check your package name